# Behaviors are only executed on some pages, while on others jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, 9

In Drupal 9, I put the following JavaScript code for an image slider and a mobile navigation into a script.js file.

```js
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  
  Drupal.behaviors.swiper = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var mainSwiper;
      mainSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
        init: false,
        rewind: settings.slide_is_rewind == "0" ? false : true,
      });
      mainSwiper.init();
      // some more code for the slider
    },
  };

  Drupal.behaviors.mobilenav = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      $(".mobile-nav-icon").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log('mobile icon clicked');
        // some more code
      });
    },
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

While the slider works great, the part of the mobile navigation isn't working as expected. It works only on pages with a slider. In the browser console, this error is thrown out.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

What's wrong with my code?

In case the issue has to do with my libraries.yml, this is its content.

```yaml
global-styling:
    version: 1.x
    css:
      theme:
        css/variables.css: {}
        css/layout.css: {}
    js:
      js/script.js: {}
  global-scripts:
    version: 1.x
    js: 
      js/navmenu.js: {}
  
  
  custom_swiper:
    version: VERSION
    css:
      theme:      
        css/swiper-bundle.min.css: { weight: -100 }
    js:
      js/swiper-bundle.min.js: {}
    dependencies:
      - core/jquery
      - core/drupal
      - core/drupalSettings
      - core/jquery.once
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inconsistent results are because `core/jquery` is being included on some pages by other libraries, and in these cases everything works fine, but you're seeing errors when there is no other library requiring `core/jquery`.

You have three libraries defined in your *libraries.yml*, however only one of them, `custom_swiper`, has dependencies defined. Dependencies need to be defined for each library individually. You need to add `core/jquery` as a dependency of the library that `script.js` is part of; per your code, this is the `global-styling` library.

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/variables.css: {}
      css/layout.css: {}
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  # ADD DEPENDENCIES
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - etc...
```

Additionally, a library can require other custom libraries defined in the same module or theme - libraries do not automagically include other libraries defined in the same *libraries.yml* file. I.e. if your `global-styling` library depends on your other library, `custom_swiper`, it will need to be added as a dependency as well. For example:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/variables.css: {}
      css/layout.css: {}
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  # ADD DEPENDENCIES
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - my_module/custom_swiper
    - etc...
```

For more information, see the [Adding assets (CSS, JS) to a Drupal theme via *.libraries.yml](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml) docs on d.o.

Comment: Thank you! After adding `- core/jquery` and `- themename/custom_swiper` as dependencies, it works. But I don't understand, why it's necessary to add `- themename/custom_swiper` at all. In `Drupal.behaviors.mobilenav` there are jQuery commands only, so I would have guessed that adding core/jquery is enough.

Comment: You may not need to add `my_module/custom_swiper`. I only noted it because I noticed one of your behaviors in `script.js` was called `swiper`, and I wanted to make sure you knew that it wouldn't be automatically included. If your code in `script.js` is unrelated to the `my_module/custom_swiper` library, but you're having issues when you don't depend on it, then the issue is likely that `script.js` depends on one or more of the other dependencies defined for `custom_swiper` and you should update your `global-styling` library to depend on those other dependencies directly.

Comment: OK, thanks, I got it!